# Python script as service has not access to asoundrc configuration file

Tags: python, raspbian, audio-recording, alsa

I have a python script that records audio from an I2S MEMS microphone, connected to a Raspberry PI 3. 
This script runs as supposed to, when accessed from the terminal. The problem appears when i run it as a service in the background.

From what i have seen, the problem is that the script as service, has no access to a software_volume i have configured in asoundrc. The strange thing is that i can see this "device" in the list of devices using the `get_device_info_by_index()` function.

For audio capturing i use the *pyaudio library* and for making the script a service i have utilized the *supervisor* utility.
Any ideas what the problem might be and how i can make my script to have access to asoundrc when it runs as a service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `~/.asoundrc` file is looked for the home directory of the current user (this is what `~` means).

Put it into the home directory of the user as which the service runs, or put the definitions into the global ALSA configuration file `/etc/asound.conf`.